# Loop inside PHP script are not executed

Tags: php, html

I have a form where i want to display the invoice_id in form input tag. And the invoice id is calculated from a php script which then is further passed by a variable to java script to get the value of input equals to that passed variable. But i don't know where i am making mistake, i am getting value that was defined in else condition in php code, don't know why php code loops won't execute. Also my table has already having 2 rows .
php code is :

```
 <?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","tssolutions");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sqlinvoice = "SELECT `invoiceid` FROM `transactiona` ORDER by `invoiceid` DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultinvoice = $conn->query($sqlinvoice);
    echo "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
if ($resultinvoice->num_rows != 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $resultinvoice->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['invoiceid'];
    $row['invoiceid'] +=1;
echo $row['invoiceid'];

        echo "      <script>        var invoid = ".$row['invoiceid']."      </script>";
    }
}
 else {
echo "      <script>        var invoid = '1';       </script>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

HTML code is :

```
<form action="./manipulate/invoice.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div style="width:15%;float:left">
Invoice #
<br>
<input style="width:98%;margin-left:1%;margin:right:1%" type="text" placeholder="Invoice ID" id="lmn">
</div>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#lmn").val(invoid);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? If you open up the console and type 'invoid' then hit enter to you see an invoice id or undefined? Are you sure the database is returning any valid value? There is literally no way we can solve this for you without more information, we can't debug code we can't run.

Comment: From what I can tell, it looks like your html form is posting to the php script, that means the php code isn't executed until you submit the form. If you want to run some php on page load, you need to organize your code differently.

Comment: i just checked console there was an error "invoid is not defined ReferenceError: invoid is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>"

Comment: In which order is this? where is the php made etc? One solution is that you have the PHP in the top of the file, make variable that stores the value ($row['invoideid'[]) and later in the javascript do $("#lmn").val("<?php echo $variable; ?>");

Comment: Why not just have PHP generate the input tags with the appropriate values already inside? Currently it looks like you script would just set all the inputs to your last input's ID because you keep overwriting `invoid`

Comment: @fyllekanin Php code already located on the top of code

Comment: @AdernNerk Then you should be able to do the solution i typed, or even better you can just when creating the input do value="<?php echo $variable; ?>"

Comment: @fyllekanin i also tried it,after implement it gives error "<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: invoid in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\TSSolution\Bill\invoice.php</b> on line <b>180</b><br />" inside input field

Comment: in your code where you are echoing the script, do you have a `$` in front of the `invoid` variable name?

Comment: @BizzyBob , yes i have included $ in front of invoid, is there any way to check if the invoid is getting value or not so that i can try using that method to figure out what problem might be ?(Beside i used once echo $invoid; in the php script it ain't get value there, so i got that problem is with php code but code doesn't have error so why invoid is not assigned value ?)

Comment: dont know why but loops are not getting executed no matter what code i write neither of loops is executed (neither if nor while), can anyone explain why ?

Comment: I am updating above question with my current code here in result it assign var invoid =1 in accordance to else condition don't know why if statement doesn't execute also my table already contains 2 rows.

Comment: You don't need the `if ($resultinvoice->num_rows != 0)` part, so take that out.  `$resultinvoice->fetch_assoc()` will return null if there aren't any rows, so that part won't be executing.  The code above does not show the `$`.  Please ensure the code above is accurate and let us know what errors/notices you get when running it.

Comment: oops, I didn't see your `else` block.  so maybe you don't want to take it out :-) , but you might need to play with it a bit to get `num_rows` to work: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#105289).  I'd take it out for now, since it is preventing you from seeing your previous problem.

Comment: @bizzybob if i remove if ($resultinvoice->num_rows != 0) from php still while loop alone won't execute , can you tell me a way how to check errors in php script ?

Comment: i have tested the query in phpmyadmin ->database-> table,with SQL it works absolute fine @bizzy

Comment: you could use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` to see the contents of your variable in the script.  so do `print_r($resultinvoice);` to see if anything is in there.  You may want to ensure you have PHP error reporting turned on at the beginning of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. If the while loop isn't running then the query isn't return any results.  mabye use `echo $conn->error` to see if there is a problem running your query..?

Comment: It showed an error in sql command "Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\TSSolution\Bill\invoice.php on line 95" and On using vardump this arose "object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }" .@bizzy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_fetch_object() returns an object, not an array of objects. So all i have to do was add $row = array(); in it, by the way thanks to all who helped me to reach the solution.

```
if ($resultinvoice->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $row = array();
    while($row = $resultinvoice->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row['invoiceid'] +=1;

        echo "      <script>        var invoid = ".$row['invoiceid']."      </script>";
    }
}
 else {
echo "      <script>        var invoid = '1';       </script>";
}
```